# How Kubernetes API Server watch mechanism works?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

Inside a kubenertes environment, there is an API Server which we can call to watch a ressource. We can call this API Server thanks a HTTP request (or WebSocket but this is not related to my question) and I wonder how the API server deals to never terminate this request and keep to notify the client of any change about the ressource.

EDIT : I mean the HTTP protocol is a request/response protocol, I know with HTTP2 we can keep a same TCP connection open to perform multiple requests but it sill has to be a request/response nature. So how the watch mechanism works with this request/response protocol ?

---

From key

The key is chunked header.

you can see a header while requesting to kube API server
`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

In doc, server can send payload continuously using this header.

In kubernetes, you can check it also

curl -v 127.0.0.1:8001/apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/<mycase :)> >

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/<mycase :)> HTTP/1.1 
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 07 Jul 2021 03:47:33 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes stores all its resources inside etcd, a key-value store, and etcd provides a watch functionality that the Kubernetes API exploits.

You can read about the etcd watch specifics [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/clientv3/watch.go).